# Umbraco XSLT list by latest versionNumber value

Tags: list, xslt, media, umbraco

I'm creating a download macro and I'm listing items from the media section by selecting the media folder they are uploaded to.

I've created a media type Asset, which has potential child nodes, Asset Version.

I can create as many Asset Version's as I like, but I only want the latest Asset Version displayed in my download macro. I've added a label to my Asset Version, versionNumber, that adds a number value created within the same Asset.

e.g.

- Asset

  - Asset Version - versionNumber = 1
  - Asset Version - versionNumber = 2
  - Asset Version - versionNumber = 3

Currently this lists only Asset Version with versionNumber = 1:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$files/Asset/AssetVersion[@nodeTypeAlias = 'AssetVersion' and versionNumber= '1']">
  <xsl:sort select="./versionNumber" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="Documents" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

I only want the latest Asset Version to display in my list, and only that version.

My download macro can list multiple Asset's, but should only display one AssetVersion for each.

e.g.
Download macro

- Asset 1

  - Asset 1 - Asset Version - versionNumber = 3
- Asset 2

  - Asset 2 - Asset Version - versionNumber = 1
- Asset 3

  - Asset 3 - Asset Version - versionNumber = 6

Can anybody help?

Cheers JV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$files/Asset">
  <!-- output here the Asset number /id -->
  <xsl:for-each select="AssetVersion[@nodeTypeAlias = 'AssetVersion']">
    <xsl:sort select="versionNumber" data-type="number" order="descending"/>

    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
      <xsl:call-template name="Documents" />
    </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks @dimitre-novatchev but that will only display one result per download macro, I've made and edit to my question. My download macro can list multiple Assets, but should only display one AssetVersion per Asset.

Comment: @JV10, See my updated answer. Do note, that without any source XML document provided, nor the exact wanted results provided, this is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks @dimitre-novatchev you've hit the nail on the head! Very impressed. Greatly appreciated!